# Jquery populate textarea from dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-io

I have created a form where users can submit data that saves as `.txt` files in a user folder. Then there is a `dropdown` on the same page that displays the file names they can select later. I am trying to populate two fields with the file name in one, and the file contents in another.

Using jQuery i can now populate the first `textfield` with the file name based on the selection, but cannot figure out how to display the file contents in the second text area.

jQuery code to populate the first `textbox` based on selection:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // apply a change event
    $('#CodeList').change(function() {
      // update input box with the currently selected value
        $('#CodeName').val($(this).val());
  });
 });
</script>
```

PHP and HTML running the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" /><input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1"><div>Below is the list of your saved codes. To edit your codes, select it from the list.</div>
<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList"><option value="0">(Add New Code)</option>
<?php
  $directory = $directory = 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];
  $filesContents = Array();
  $files = scandir( $directory ) ;

  foreach( $files as $file )
 {
  if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
 {
  $filesContents[$file] = file_get_contents($directory , $file);
  echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
 }
}
?>
</select>
        <h3>Saved Codes</h3>
        <form method="post" action="/evo/avsaveprocess.php">

            <input type="hidden" name="Action" value="SAVE" />
            <input type="hidden" name="CodeId" id="CodeId" value="0" />
            <table width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="CodeDescription" size="40" maxlength="50" id="CodeName" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Code:</td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea rows="10" style="width:99%" name="Code" id="CodeValue"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried? `$.get( "DIRECTORY/FILE.EXT" );`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // apply a change event
    $('#CodeList').change(function() {
      // update input box with the currently selected value
        $('#CodeName').val($(this).val());
        $.get( '<? echo $directory ?>' + '/' + $('#CodeName').val(), function( data ) {
            $( "#CodeValue" ).text( data );
        });
  });
 });
</script>
```

I don't know if it works, please let me know the behaviour and we'll try to fix if there is a problem.

Comment: I have not, no, I am testing the code now, thank you for the assist.

Comment: that ALMOST did it. It returned [object] [object] in the second text area saying the address was not found but thats because it appears to be trying to find the file in the base folder. its looking for the address as: http://mywebsite.com/evo/Addiction.txt , when it needs to pull from the /users/ folder , http://mywebsite.com/evo/users/Addiction.txt , am not sure what to change to pull form the right directory in the $.get syntax

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The `#CodeName` value is mywebsite.com/evo/Addiction.txt ?

Comment: the codename value is the name of the file, which is addiction.txt. When I run the script the get command comes back with: GET http://roleplayevolution.com/evo/Addiction.txt 404 (Not Found), presumably being unable to get the file contents because its not finding the file in the right location. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Will it be always allocated in `/users/` ? I'm modifying my answer if that's the case.

Comment: They're located in /users/their user name which is based on the session id which is shown in the php for populating the dropdown box. The directory the files are in is: 'users/' . $_SESSION['username'];

Comment: try the new version I've made. the `<script>` must be after the `form`. Preferably at the end of the page.

Comment: Moved it and ran, it came back saying uncaught reference error: users is not defined in this line: $('#CodeValue').val($.get( users/Addiction + '/' + $('#CodeName').val()));

Comment: Oh, sorry. i've forgot to quote. Try now.

Comment: That seems to have resolved it. Only the only thing it shows in that second box for the file contents is [object object] when there is text in there, it just isn't displaying for some reason.

Comment: I believe in jquery there is a way to specify datatype on the returned file so it knows its plain text which may be the issue I'm just not sure where it would go or how to write it, could that be causing it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought and I changed it and tried it on my own. Now it should work perfectly!

Comment: Barbarity, you are an absolute savior. Thank you so so very much for your help. I wasn't sure how to put it in there, but at least I know what it was, haha. I can't thank you enough for all of your help. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do file operations for this and you cannot directly write `$('#CodeName').val($(this).val());`

There is a HTML5 API of interest.

The [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)which allows you to read files (of a users choice). Most modern browsers implement this.

I presume you can also use IE only [ActiveX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972(v=vs.85).aspx)controls to do file manipulation on windows, only if it's relevant to you.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770645/file-operation-using-javascript-or-jquery)**